# Java 2 minute delay sometimes when connecting socket?

Tags: java, linux, sockets, kotlin

I'm baffled with the following mystery. When testing my application, I frequently (maybe 25% of the time) get a two minute delay when connecting an SSL socket. I'm using Java 8, Ubuntu 16.04. When I use wireshark I can see that nothing is sent over the network to the target server. Maybe there could be other network traffic like DNS resolving. The delay is always 2 minutes with an uncertainty of no more than a couple seconds. The last log message before it hangs is:

```
DEBUG org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory - Connecting socket to redacted:443 with timeout 0
```

Pausing in a debugger verifies that it's blocked in socket connect code in class PlainSocketImpl:

```
native void socketConnect(InetAddress address, int port, int timeout)
```

I'm pretty sure I'd have noticed if this hang happens to other applications, I think it just affects my Java program. My (Kotlin) code is as follows:

```
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost
import org.apache.http.config.RegistryBuilder
import org.apache.http.conn.socket.ConnectionSocketFactory
import org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory
import org.apache.http.entity.StringEntity
import org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient
import org.apache.http.impl.client.HttpClients
import org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager
import org.apache.http.util.EntityUtils
import java.security.SecureRandom
import javax.net.ssl.*

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
  val client = SSLClient()

  val auth = AuthRequest()
  val ares = auth.post(client)
  val token = ares.value
  println(token)
}

class SSLClient {
    val client : CloseableHttpClient

    init {
        val config = Config
        config.loadCerts()
        val ctx = SSLContext.getInstance("TLSv1.2")
        val kmf = KeyManagerFactory.getInstance(KeyManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm())
        kmf.init(config.clientSSLCerts, config.keyPassword.toCharArray())
        val tmf = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance(TrustManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm())
        tmf.init(config.serverSSLCerts)
        ctx.init(kmf.keyManagers, tmf.trustManagers, SecureRandom())
        val sslsf = SSLConnectionSocketFactory(ctx)

        val r = RegistryBuilder.create<ConnectionSocketFactory>()
                .register("https", sslsf)
                .build()
        val cm = PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager(r)
        client = HttpClients.custom()
                .setConnectionManager(cm)
                .build()
    }

    fun post(endpoint : String) : HttpPost {
        val post = HttpPost(endpoint)
        post.addHeader("Content-Type", "application/xml")
        return post
    }

    fun execute(post : HttpPost, xmlBody : String) : String {
        println(xmlBody)
        post.entity = StringEntity(xmlBody, Charsets.UTF_8)
        client.execute(post).use { response ->
            response.allHeaders.forEach { println(it.toString()) }
            println(response.statusLine.toString())
            if (response.statusLine.statusCode !in 200..299) {
                throw Exception(response.statusLine.toString())
            }
            val entity = response.entity
            if (entity == null || entity.contentLength == 0L) {
                throw Exception("No body content in HTTP response")
            }
            val result = EntityUtils.toString(entity)
            println(result)
            return result
        }
    }
}
```

The last clue I have to offer is that the time spent paused in the debugger doesn't count towards the two minutes. I can wait five minutes with it paused, unpause it and it will still take exactly two minutes. That tells me it's not waiting for an external process to complete because the external process would make progress during the paused time.

Comment: have you tried looking at the connection with a packet sniffer eg Wireshark?

Comment: I did and mentioned the results literally in the first paragraph.

Comment: Just a wild guess from similar delays I experienced with WebStart signatures: Java might try to contact the CA if the SSL certificate has been revoked.

Comment: Just strace it and also get a thread dump when it's waiting. You should also trace all network and/or filesystem activity rather than just the one connection.

Comment: DNS resolve timeout by default is only 5s.

Comment: Do you have a stack trace of the pause? Post it in your question if so.

Comment: Run with java.net.debug property set to all, i.e. `java -Djavax.net.debug=all ...`

Comment: This went away by itself, I never figured out what caused it or what fixed it